# If I have an application with a flask API, do I need to put the whole application into a webserver like gunicorn?

Tags: python, api, flask, gunicorn

This is probably a very odd question and I apologize to begin with.

I'm having the strange situation that previous developers of the project I am working on have decided to split up the application into the application and the flask api run with gunicorn.the gunicorn/api will simply modify some configuration files, and the main application will then react to the changes of the configuration file (in theory).

Now, there would be some benefits to combining these two processes. And I wanted to ask you guys what's the best thing to do.

I thought about simply running the flask app from the main application - but the integrated flask server is not suited for production.

Now my queston is, to combine the two parts of the application, would I have to put the whole application into one and then run that from a webserver like gunicorn?

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you ask. I would expect that `application` meas program which I can run on my local computer (or it can be used by many persons on they local computers) and `flask API` runs on server (in local network or in cloud) but not on local computer - and then `flask API` can't be combined with `application` and it can't be run from `application` - it has to be run separatelly on server and it could be good to use tools which will run it fast and safe - ie gunicorn + supervisord. In production flask shouldn't be run as `app.run()`

Comment: OR maybe your `application` means `web page` which can run together with `fask API` on the same server? Then `application` can run with gunicorn - and it comminicate with `flask API` using `localhost` - but I would also start it with gunicorn. And I would start it separatelly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it. It's neither an application to be used on a personal computer nor a webpage. It's an application that controls devices. And multiple devices have to communicate with each other, and for that purpose, they all have a flask API.